# Can we create products which are not visible in Catelog Search but on product view page in magento?

Tags: php, magento, search

I have some products like,

Panasonic Lumix DMC-LS5 Silver,Panasonic DMC-S2 Violet

And Master product like, Panasonic Lumix DMC

So,i don't want to display first 2 products in Search but i want to display in Master product view page as related products in magento.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add the master product as a configurable product and set the visibility to 'catalog, search'. If you then add the other 2 product as simple variants with the visibility of 'not visible individually'. This then enable yours configurable product to be what shows within your search and category navigation views, though when you visit the page then you will have the variants available as a selection.

You may also need to create an attribute for the variations, such as 'Camera Model'if no suitable attribute already exists.